Courses or lectures or books on machine learning or AI in general that have a lot of theoretical and practical mathematics but also practical coding
I'm looking for deep learning, or machine learning more generally, or artificial intelligence more generally, courses or lectures or books, that have a lot of theoretical and practical mathematics but also practical coding! Text form works, I prefer video form, but ideally if it has both text and video form!
I love Stanford CS229: Machine Learning and other Stanford courses but that has basically just the theory mathematics part. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoROMvodv4rNyWOpJg_Yh4NSqI4Z4vOYy
I love Karpathy's neural networks zero to hero but that's mostly coding and not much mathematics and it's mostly deep learning and not rest of machine learning. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAqhIrjkxbuWI23v9cThsA9GvCAUhRvKZ
Coursera courses seem to have a lot of code but not really much theory and mathematics. https://www.coursera.org/collections/machine-learning
Dive into deep learning seems to cover a lot with mathematics and code but I wish it was in video form too! https://www.d2l.ai/chapter_preface/index.html
And lots of these don't cover neurosymbolic methods or other methods in AI, which I dont really need in one place with all of the others, but it would be great bonus!
